# UV mapping problem - separated triangles instead of one surface

Tags: uv

I'm new to blender so this is certainty a simple question but i have searched for a solution and can't find any. 
I am trying to UV map an imported CAD model which is a simple beam (se picture below). The problem is that what is one single surface gets divided into several **separated** triangles in the UV mapping. How do I merge the triangles into one surface?

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5327" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5327/)

Comment: Hello :). Please choose an answer to mark as accepted, or write your own solution. (it keeps popping up as unanswered). Big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just answering this, so it can be removed from unanswered :).

You need to

1. Apply scale (its at 0,001)
2. Merge double vertices (122 overall)
3. Then UV unwrap

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your edges may not be conected,example:[image: ex1] Try going to the vertex selection mode and merge all vertex that overlap(if you are with difficulty to select them go to the wireframe mode [press Z] and use box selection [press B] to get all of them ).

[image: ex2]

if you are willing to remake all the mesh properly, make everything from a cube or a plane extruding it faces, i dont know how you got to the triangles.

Now that your mesh is fixed, you need to mark the seams in order to get a proper uvmap.
[image: ex3]
NOTE: only mark seams were you want to get cut in your UV map.

if you want to know more about uv maps or modeling i recommend to watch tutorial before, it really helps.

hope this helps.

Comment: Here You have a short video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6OXSR5Ynyc. Everything needed is there with seam marks for sure. As Diogo said next time please try to model object Yo-self cause imported thing could cause troubles especially when made from triangles.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Unfortunately I still don't get it to work. I have watched all tutorial I can find about UV mapping but in all the tutorials the model is very simple and the goal is often to "cut" the model to make the UV map better. But in my case I want to do the opposite, to join parts in the UV map.

Comment: The background to why I am imported the model instead of creating it myself is that in my work as a production engineer I am importing a CAD model of our factory into a VR model using Unity. The picture i attached in my question is only a very small part of a much more complex model. So to re-create all the parts would take too long.

Comment: I would much appreciate if you can take a look at my model that i attached in the comment of my question and see if there is something that can be done to make a better UV mapping. If it is not possible I will remake the parts like you suggest but only the parts that is most important and live with that most of the parts don't have any texture.

Comment: I think that a good part of the problem is caused because its an imported file, try finding better ways to convert the cad file to blend or simply start everything from scratch in blender because maybe fixing this problem in every model would take longer then fixing what is causing